# Accord: "comparé(s/e/es) à ..."

Tags: accord

> **Comparé(s/e/es) aux** deux autres nations, les défis auxquels est confrontée la France sont plus complexes.

I have always wondered which part of a sentence should affect the accord of the expression "comparé(s/e/es) à ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, *compar**ée*** apply to *la France* but the sentence is somewhat odd. I'd rather write:

> *Compar**és** **à ceux des** deux autres nations, **les défis** auxquels est confrontée la France sont plus complexes.*